# How to structure data for heavy reports in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift, reporting, scalability

I am using a MySQL database for my SaaS application. The structure is mostly around the business using our platform. So we have the following tables:

```
business
contacts - contains business id
sales - contains business id and contact id
payments - contains sale id
sale items - contains sale id
memberships - contains contact id and sale item id
events - contains business id
bookings - contains event id and contact id
```

I am looking to create some reports and store some data for analytics without writing complex queries again and again.

Should I create a new table in MySQL with aggregated data per customer, such as total class booked/missed/attended, total payments amount etc.

Or should I use something like aws redshift to have a data warehouse for this?

Comment: Why would you need to write complex queries again and again? You could put them in a procedure and call the procedure.. ON the other hand you might consider OLAP

Comment: There will be a lot of data and a lot of joins. I want to keep the aggregated data somewhere else because we might need it to run some automations etc. let’s say I want to find out how many classes did a customer book using a specific membership. Instead of calculating again and again for each customer I can just have it stored already in that way